# pgRouting - Route between multiple destinations - in order

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I want to calculate the route between multiple points, respecting the order of the list.

For example, if I have the following list:

1. Lat: -40, Long: -30
2. Lat: -41, Long: -31
3. Lat: -40.5, Long: -30.5

I want the route to go from point 1 to 2, and then from point 2 to 3.

- I **don't** want to calculate the best path from 1 to 2 and 3 (Travelling Sales Person) because that would give me a path 1-3-2, as the 1st point is closer to the 3rd point than the 2nd one.
- I **don't** want to calculate the best path from 1 to 2, and from 1 to 3 (Mutliple destination Shortest Path Dijkstra), because that would give me a path from 1 to 2 and from 1 to 3.

**I want** it to calculate the best path from 1 to 2, and then from 2 to 3. All with just 1 query, using pgrouting.

It would be something like a TSRP but preserving the order of the points. Google already does that (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) and if you want, they can optimize the order of the waypoints (using TSRP)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to execute desired shortest path algorithm twice, first from 1 to 2 and second from 2 to 3.

Comment: So I'd need to run N-1 queries for N points? Is that the only way?

Comment: Also, I'd have another problem with that approach: for example, if points 2 and 3 are in the same highway, it would arrive to point 2 and then go directly to point 3, in the opposite direction as it was going.

Comment: Wont be problem if you use dijkstra(or other routin) with oneway street support (if your data supports it)

Comment: and that way, how will dijkstra know that I was going in one direction, and not the other? I mean, in a two-way street... The next query will give me a result in the opposite direction.

Comment: With N points, the vehicle can face in 2 directions for each point. Meaning you have 2^N combinations to test for the best direction at each point. Because changing direction for one point, affects the next ones. But if some of them are oneway, there is no choice and the number of combinations is reduced a lot, since only sequences of twoway streets need to be tested individually. I'm not sure if pgrouting can handle it, but our RW Net 4 product can.

Comment: see http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html , It is all about how you create topology. For an example i have Finnish Digiroad data , which has that data. So i can calculate reverse_cost to be some huge number for oneway streets.

Comment: I'm doing this like you recommended me. But i have the problem that it's really slowly. isn't there any other way to make it faster? Google Directions does it in milliseconds! How?!

Comment: Well google probably has all data in memory or something. Few optimizations for postgresql : Use bounding box to limit used data ( i assume that you already have indexes ), change postgresql setting to use more memory (defaults basicly just make sure that you can start it on every machine) , load route table into tablespace which is on RAMdisk. With indexes and postgresql memory setting you should get (on amd X2 + 8G RAM) under 1 sec (500ms max, if data in cache then under 200ms) results for countries like finland or denmark using osm data, it is faster if you can limit data